# How do I rename an 8 character file to a 9 character file through batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have the following files:

s1234567

12345678.TXT

23456789.TXT

The file name that begins with s changes daily with random numbers. 
I want to rename the file beginning with s####### (8 character file name) to sr####### (9 character file name) on a daily basis.

When I try the following for s1234567, I get sr234567 (8 character file name) instead of sr1234567 (9 character file name).

```
ren s* sr*
```

I currently have a script that prompts for the numbers in the file, then renames the file using the numbers for the desired result.  What I'm trying to figure out is how do I rename the file s####### (8 character file name) to sr####### (9 character file name) through Windows batch scripting without prompting.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ren` command requires its second argument to have no wildcards.  What you have in mind would be better suited by [jren.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) or [rename.pl](https://github.com/casret/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/rename.pl).  To use the cmd interpreter's `ren` or `rename` command, you'll need a `for` loop.  Here's one solution.

```
@echo off
setlocal

for %%I in (s*) do (
    set "base=%%~nI"

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    ren "%%~fI" "!base:s=sr!%%~xI"
    endlocal
)
```

It's unclear in your example whether you need to add an "r" to filenames that don't contain an S, or whether some base filenames are already 9 characters in length, or whether "s" can occur in other positions.  But hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: Thank you!  This script produces the desired outcome.  Now I need to figure out how it works.

Comment: What do you want to know? The `for` loop loops through every file matching `s*`, assigning one to `%%I` on each iteration.  The tilde notation returns parts of the filename: `~f` for fully qualified `drive:\\path\filename.ext`; `~n` for the basename without extension, and `~x` for the extension. See the last two pages of `help for` in a cmd console for more info. Delayed expansion allows variables to be evaluated within a parenthetical code block, waiting for each loop before expanding. Also, read up on [substring substitution](http://dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.Replace).